# TestNg Eclipse Plugin - NullPointer when start test

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, testng, testng-eclipse

When I try to run a testNg class, I immidiatly recieve this error about a NullPointerException (see log below).

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2016-06-10 11:58:27.039
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Launching ConvertionManagerTest".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.osgi.framework.Version.<init>(Version.java:125)
 at org.testng.eclipse.launch.TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(TestNGLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:74)
 at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
 at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
 at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
 at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

I've tried to not install optional component (M2E Integration) of plugin as see in others question on Stackoverflow but it doesnt resolve the problem.

It seems somethings about the configuration of TestNG but confronting it with a RunConfiguration on a installation where all works, they are equals.

Any Ideas?

Comment: It seems to be an issue and I created a new issue. Could you follow it and help to fix it if missedone need more information? https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/257

Answer (score 1):

could you provide more info to help diagnose this issue. 
what's the Java Version in your launch configuration? what's the Eclipse version?

please share the details to the corresponding ticket on github: https://github.com/cbeust/testng-eclipse/issues/257

thanks